# Is it possible to optimize this expression

Tags: haskell

```
check x = filter((==0) . (\(x,y) -> x `mod` y)) $ zip (replicate 20 x)  [1..20]
main = do 
   print $ take 1 $ filter ((==20) . length) [check x | x <- [1..]]
```

I'm trying to run the above via `http://www.compileonline.com/compile_haskell_online.php` but it appears to be using too much resources as the number being evaluated increases and so I can search for `filter(==18)` but not `filter(>=19)`. Is there anyway to optimize the expression so that it would run?

Comment: You can check whether there is any remainder by `any (>0) $ map ((mod) x) [1..20]`

Answer (score 7):

I think here the task must be solved completely differently.

It looks like you are looking for the first number that can be divided by all numbers `[1..20]`. I propose you find all prime divisors of all numbers in the range, and find the product of maximum powers of all primes.

Comment: Well, you can also just calculate this number, which must be the least common multiple of the numbers from 1 to 20, which is 232792560.
You can calculate it in haskell with `foldl' lcm 1 [1 .. 20]`.

Comment: @chaosmasttter there is a much cheaper way to do it: `product [16,9,5,7,11,13,17,19]` - in other words, find all primes less than N, then for each such prime find the greatest power of that prime that is still less than N.

Comment: but for this you have to figure out these numbers, which `lcm` implicitly does for you.

Comment: @chaosmasttter yes, I said "cheaper" :)